# Pagination next button doesnt work. How to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on pagination and previous button working perfectly fine

```
const handlePage = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement> | any) => {
  dispatch(setJobsOptions({
    ...currentFilters,
    page: Number(event.currentTarget.getAttribute("value")),
  }));
};


<button
  value={Number.isNaN(currentPage) ? "" : (currentPage - 1).toString()}
  onClick={handlePage}
>
{`<`}
</button>
```

however I want similar logic to the next button  and doesnt work..

```
<button
  value={Number.isNaN(currentPage) ? "" : (currentPage + 1).toString()}
  onClick={handlePage}
>
{`>`}
</button>
```

How to fix {`>`} button?

Comment: what does your `handlePage` function look like?

Comment: @Taxel I have added the handlePage

Comment: What does inspect show the value for both buttons?

Comment: @SameerKumarJain button for prev showing value 0 however value for next is 2